# Remove specific visual filter from report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a report with 10 visuals . How can I remove filter from the selected visual?
If I select any one of the visual then it's applied filter should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your issue correct, you are basically looking for disable interaction between visuals. Like, if you select country = A from visual 1, you still wants all country list in visual 2. If this is correct, follow this below steps-

**Step-1:** Select visual 1 and go to **format** tab from the ribbon and the **edit interaction** option as shown below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Now you can control your visual 2 should interact with visual 1 or not selecting either **filter** or **none** option as shown below. select **None** in visual 2 and it will give your expected output-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the filters from the selected visual, you can use
`updateFilters` and to get the details of the selected visual, you can use `dataSelected` event. Please find the below relevant code snippet:

Call `dataSelected` event:

```js
report.on("dataSelected",async function (event) {
    const pages = await report.getPages();

    // Retrieve the active page.
    let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
        return page.isActive
    })[0];

    const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

    // Retrieve the event details
    let data = event.detail;

    // Retrieve the target visual.
    let visual = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
        return visual.name === data.visual.name;
    })[0];
        
        // Remove the filers applied to the visual
    await visual.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.RemoveAll);
});
```

Please find the references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#dataselected
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters#filters-operation